# Quantile regression does not give expected result regarding costs

Tags: regression, machine-learning, quantiles, quantile-regression

I want to predict the length of an event. When I underestimate the event length it costs me 2€ (per minute) while an overestimation costs 1€ (per minute). To capture this price inbalance I tried using LightGBM quantile regression with alpha=0.67 (67% quantile).

My expectation was that this would perfectly translate my business objective into a machine-learning objective but out of curiosity I ran several checks with many different runs and it turns out that the 71%-quantile creates the lowest costs for me on average when I do an overall cost calculation with the aforementioned numbers using the actual and the predicted values of the different models.

How is that possible?

Comment: Why exactly should this translate to your business objective?

Comment: Because choosing alpha=0.67 when using quantile regression leads to a loss function that taxes underestimates twice as much as overestimates. Intuitivly I thought that this would give me predictions that minimize costs when the cost for an underestimate is twice as high as for an overestimate.

Comment: If you repeat your process, say, 1000 times with bootstrap samples, what confidence interval do you get for the quantile?

Comment: @Dave Somebody is using up all my cores right now and I will be on vaccation until friday so I can't tell you the confidence interval until then. However, I am quite confident that 0.67 was not optimal for my problem but a higher quantile. I did test it with 30 bootstrap samples per quantile and the minimum was clearly somewhere around the 71% quantile.

Comment: @Dave I tested it again and I'm sure that 67% does not minimize the cost ratio of 2:1. Any idea why?